# jQuery - shuffling two absolutely positioned elements

Tags: jquery

I have a container called three. It has the two divs inside as 'one' and 'two'. I would just like to shuffle their absolute positions. Is it possible? If so, is there any built-in function with [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery)?

This is my try, but it does not work properly:

#### HTML:

```
<div id='three'>
    <div id="one">1</div>
    <div id="two">2</div>
</div>
```

#### Code:

```
var clone1 = $('#one').clone();
var colone2 = $('#two').clone();

var clone1X = $('#two').position().left
var clone1Y = $('#two').position().top;

var clone2X = $('#one').position().left;
var clone2Y = $('#one').position().top;

$('div > div').remove();

$('div').append($(colone2).css({left:clone1X,top:clone1Y})).append($(clone1).css({left:clone2X,top:clone2Y}));
```

But does not work as I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be that hard... Here is how it would go,

```
<div id='three'>
    <div id="one">1</div>
    <div id="two">2</div>
</div>

$(function () {
    var onePos = $('#one').position();
    var twoPos = $('#two').position();

    $('#one').css({left: twoPos.left, top: twoPos.top});
    $('#two').css({left: onePos.left, top: onePos.top});
});
```

Comment: yes, you are correct. very simple thing. but i deeply think to shuffle the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in function for that in jQuery. But we can always create our own:

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.swap = function(other,speed) {
        //Get the position
        var position1 = this.offset();
        var position2 = other.offset();

        //Position this where it is
        this.css({
            top: position1.top + 'px',
            left: position1.left + 'px',
            position: 'absolute'
        });

        //Position the other element where it is
        other.css({
            top: position2.top + 'px',
            left: position2.left + 'px',
            position: 'absolute'
        });

        this.animate({
            'top': position2.top + 'px',
            'left': position2.left + 'px'
        }, speed, function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });

        other.animate({
            'top': position1.top + 'px',
            'left': position1.left + 'px'
        }, speed, function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    };
})( jQuery );
```

Using this function:

```
$('#trigger').click(function(e) {
    $('#element1').swap($('#element2'),300);
});
```